# Networking not working on Docker / Centos 7.9

Tags: docker, networking

I'm running Docker on Centos 7.9.2009 and have a very strange issue. The containers do not have network access and cannot be accessed from the host. I've searched for potential solutions, a lot of which seem to be related to DNS issues (which I don't think is what's going on here since even pinging 8.8.8.8 from within the container does not work). I've tried installing iptables-service, restarting iptables & docker in that order, full reboot etc.

In my efforts to try and find what the problem might be, I ran tcpdump in a separate terminal. As soon as I did, everything works fine! Kill the tcpdump process and it all stops - no network access. Any suggestions of why running tcpdump may resolve the problem? Is it something to do with tcpdump listening on docker0 and establishing a network state?

Output of tcpdump on startup:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on docker0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
```

Output of uname -a:

```
Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 19 22:10:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of /etc/redhat-release:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
```

Output of ip addr:

```
3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
link/ether 02:42:8b:94:46:19 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::42:8bff:fe94:4619/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output of iptables --list -t nat:

```
  Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !loopback/8           ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        anywhere

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Output of docker version:

```
    Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        4484c46d9d
 Built:             Wed Sep 16 17:03:45 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.13
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       4484c46d9d
  Built:            Wed Sep 16 17:02:21 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.3.7
  GitCommit:        8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `tcpdump` starts listetning an interface, it puts that interface into [promiscuous mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode).
That's the immediate reason why your container networking starts working.

Normally `docker0` does not require promiscuous mode to work.
Behavior you described indicates problems in your networking stack.

First, your Linux kernel is pretty old.
Version `3.10.0-327` was [released in year 2015](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3078#RHEL7) by Redhat.
Check for [this issue](https://serverfault.com/a/1036189/405997) - looks like exactly the same problem.
The author managed to solve it with kernel upgrade and `br_netfilter` module fix.

Also in couple of other cases ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61472105/4486909), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61472076/4486909)) just removing the interface and Docker restart helped.
But I think you still need to upgrade the kernel - it's too old, really.

Comment: Thanks Olesya. I've upgraded to 3.10.0-1160.6.1 and it seems to have fixed the issue. Appreciate the explanation and the help!